# How to install Lodash

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm new to lodash and i've have installed lodash as

```
npm i --save lodash
```

and im calling it in my index.js file as

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

However this is not working and its displaying the error on console as

> index.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier '_'

Im not using node.js

Comment: There are instructions on the homepage for the library. https://lodash.com/

Comment: First of all im not using node.js so this isnt a repeat, second i've tried  that

Comment: You skipped straight past the "in a browser" bit and onto "Using npm" … which is the package manager for Node.js which you claim you aren't using (and then from there you dived into ES6 imports which aren't mentioned anywhere on that page).

Comment: Use [napa](https://github.com/shama/napa) to install `lodash.js` straight from github into `node_modules`: i.e. `npm i napa` then in your `package.json` specify a napa config block `"napa": {"lodash": "lodash/lodash#3.10.1"}` and also configure napa to run upon npm install with `"scripts": {"install": "napa"}`. You'll then have `node_modules/lodash/lodash.js`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using node.js try the following

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

Comment: No im not using node.js ... any other ideas

Comment: @AkshayKishore — If you're not using node then where did npm come from?